# /warp, /sethome, /home, /bal, and /pay aren't working with Essentials 1.10 Plugin

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I have a server and I use the Essentials plugin but for some reason the commands in the title aren't working. It works with OPs but nobody else. Here are the permissions:

```
groups:
  Default:
    default: true
    build:true
    permissions:
    - -bukkit.command.plugins
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.pay.list
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.spawn
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.bal
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing this wrong?
Here are my plugins:

- Essentials
- Essentials Group Manager
- RedProtect
- iDisguise
- multiworld

I'm not super good with this stuff so you might have to explain it in simple terms.
I use CraftBukkit FYI.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I mean, what Minecraft-server software is it? Is this Spigot, bukkit, etc.? server.pro offers multiple options, and it would help to know which you're having this problem with.

Comment: Oh it's CraftBukkit sorry.

Comment: Do any other commands work or is it just about the ones stated? Are there maybe any error messages in the console/log?

Comment: Essentials is the root of all problems. Btw. try to recreate the file and then don't write into it, but use commands in console to add permissions. And even better, use apropriate plugin for handling permissions, for example PEX or similar.

Comment: It's mostly just these ones that don't work that I'd like to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used PEX and it works. It's a great permission system, and it is easy to give people prefixes / suffixes, especially if you give them a group to be in! Thanks for the help!

I also needed to put "schema-version: 1" in thanks to PEX so now it's great.

Answer (score 1):

The normal essentials version is very outdated, you should use essentialsX(CI Server: https://ci.drtshock.net/job/EssentialsX/)! If essentialsX also does not works it has to do with EssentialsGroupmanager! I recommend you go use LuckPerms(Spigot:  https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/luckperms-an-advanced-permissions-system.28140/) as your permissions system, it is very updated and has a nice dev. It also has a lot more function than groupmanager!

Comment: md5 also maintains a version of the last formal Essentials release, which can be downloaded [Spigot's Jenkins](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/Spigot-Essentials/) server. Source is available on [Spigot's Stash](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/PLUGIN/repos/essentials/browse) server. Obviously, this is just a maintenance version. EssentialsX will have additional improves and features.

Comment: Essentials GroupManager is more outdated than Essentials itself.

Comment: @Frelling I didn't knew that. Nice to know!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a .* to the end of each permission node, one by one, to see if that solves the problem. Sometimes the node is just pointing to the name, not the command itself, and a .* can sometimes help a lot, without revealing too much control over the server, etc.

Hope this helps!